# Installing .whl file on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am currently trying to host my Python Django-powered website on Heroku but the CLI failed during installation of a required package, Numpy+Mkl (pip could not find links for the package).

I have installed the package on my dev server through the .whl file I have download in Christoph Gohlke's online repository of python packages.

I am wondering if are there some ways I could install this package on Heroku? Or do I have to find other hosting sites? If yes, can you recommend a better hosting site?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Did you try [`numpy-mkl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-mkl)?

Comment: the error says it could install the requirement numpy+mkl because it not find the link file during git push line.

Comment: Hi chris, the numpy+mkl in your link is version 1.10.2 I am currently using version 1.11.2. I will try to downgrade it and see if it works. thanks!